# Inserting a element into REACT child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am rendering a chart with react, and I would like to add an element to the title of that chart. Unfortunately, I am using a shared chart component, and majorly modifying the component would be difficult to justify.

I have tried using refs; however, I'm running into difficulty figuring how to actually append a virtual dom element as a child element.

Specific Chart Class:

```
class ChartWithInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.chartWrapperElement = React.createRef();        
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
        const infoInsertion = (
            <div>
               <IconButton/>
            </div>
        )
        this.chartWrapperElement.current.insertBefore(infoInsertion, this.chartWrapperElement.current.firstChild);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GenericChart
                variables={this.props.variables}
                ref={this.chartWrapperElement}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Generic Chart Class

```
export default class EmbeddedChart extends PureComponent {
    // Random methods //
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.props.ref} id={'chartDiv'}>
                Chart
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The expected result would essentially be:

```
<div id='chartDiv'>
   <IconButton/>
</div>


What is the most react way to do this? Am I missing something with refs?
```

Comment: Can you just render your button on top of the chart? And then put them both in the same React parent component?

Comment: Can you give us some screenshots?

Comment: @CyclopeanCity your answer was good enough for this case; however, there are still cases where the formating may be applied to a div that surrounds the generic chart element. In this case, that wasn't the problem and I could use your style (thank you!), but for future reference, is there another way to do this?

Comment: In a React app even a basic div should be inside a React component of some sort, so you could still use this the same way, by putting the button in that component's child. The React solution for this type of problem is just "composition" or wrapping components. They explain why here https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html and have an example similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

React is meant for components and if you follow the separation of concern and component architecture. You can segregate all your components and individual reusable components. Create your button component separately and import anywhere else. Bind your events and business logic respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about this last part. Essentially, the generic chart contains a lot more inside of the // Random Methods // that we wouldn't want to replicate every single time we build a chart (ie to make chart type 1, chart type 2, etc). The special case about this chart is that it needs an info button near the title. I understand I should normally assemble each component from it's base components, but in this case, its a small add to justify creating an entirely copied component.